# What am I misunderstanding about angular state promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

This is `appRouteConfig.js` state where
I use `$promise` to verify userList:

```
.state('userAccounts',{
    url:'/userAccounts',
    controller:'UserAccount',
    resolve:{
        registerService: "registerService",
        userList: function(registerService){                            
            return registerService.AllUser().$promise; 
        }
    },
    templateUrl:'UserAccounts/UserAccountsView.html'
})
```

This is `registerService.js`

```
    AllUser: function(){
        return $http.get('api/allUser');
    }
```

Without using `$promise` it works properly.

I want to know why using $promise here does not work. If this is not clear please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works properly when you remove it because in your registerService.js you are already returning a promise:

```
AllUser: function(){
        return $http.get('api/allUser');
    }
```

Which is what happens when you return an $http request. So when you tell it to return it in your resolve you only need:

```
resolve:{
        registerService: "registerService",
        userList: function(registerService){                            
            return registerService.AllUser(); 
        }
```

Otherwise with .$promise on the end you are telling it to get the promise of a promise.